# print and format output

Tags: python

I have a simple script:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print "%d%d%d%d%d" % ( now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute )
```

result:

```
20111124149
```

How to get result:

```
201111241409
```

?

Comment: Use datetime.strftime for formatting timestamps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify that the numbers should have width two and be zero-padded:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d" % ( now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute )
```

If we break one of the components down, we get:

- `%` marks the start of a substitution target.
- `0` makes the result zero-padded.
- `2` means, that the result should be 2 characters wide.
- `d` means that it's a decimal value.

#### Further information:

- [String Formatting Operations in the Python manual](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Comment: +1; a good explanation of the `%02d` (even if it's still the wrong tool for the job :P).

Answer (score 7):

Method one: use `%02d` instead of `%d`. This pads up to width two with leading zeros.

```
print "%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d" % (now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute)
```

Method two, the correct way: use [`datetime.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime).

```
print now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
```

For explanation of the format string, see [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) in the Python docs.

Comment: Advanced string formatting of `datetime` objects uses `strftime`, so you can also use `"{0:%Y%m%d%H%M}".format(now)`.

Comment: @eryksun: Interesting, wasn't aware of that.

Comment: For CPython 2.x, it's on the last line of the [date_format](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Modules/datetimemodule.c#l2544) function in datetimemodule.c.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this approach:

```
print "{0:02d}{1:02d}{2:02d}{3:02d}{4:02d}".format(now.year, now.month, now.day, 
                                                   now.hour, now.minute)
```

The `format`-method should be preferred over the old formatting syntax. You can find more information on how to write the formatting-string [here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print "%d%02d%02d%02d%02d" % (now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute)
```